# how can I change the exponential value to decimal?

Tags: pgfplots, nodes-near-coords

I want to make my plot completely in decimal. I used the function

```
\pgfkeys{
    /pgf/number format/precision=1, 
    /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill=true
}
```

to make my decimal like 2.0 instead of only 2. Now I am facing a problem that my value which was 0.2 now changed to 2.0 x10exp2. I want it back to 0.2. Please help. Code and pic is given.[image: <code>plot after using pgfkeys function</code>]

```
\begin{figure}[htb!]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfkeys{
     /pgf/number format/precision=1, 
    /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill=true
}
\begin{axis}[
ybar, ymax=4, ymin=0,
%enlargelimits=0.10,
legend style={at={(0.5,-0.20)},
anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
ylabel={Surface Roughness (nm)},
xlabel={Substrate},
symbolic x coords={Glass,Silicon,PEN},
xtick=data,
nodes near coords,
nodes near coords align={vertical},
]
\addplot [fill= white] coordinates {(Glass,2.4) (Silicon,1.1) (PEN,1.8)};
\addplot [fill = black] coordinates  {(Glass,1.1) (Silicon,0.2) (PEN,1.0)};

\legend{Profilometer,AFM}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\caption{Substrate Vs IBD Surface Roughness(Avg)}
\label{Subvibd}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The key `fixed zerofill` only applies numbers that also use the `fixed` style (that's a bit confusing). So if you set

```
\pgfkeys{
     /pgf/number format/precision=1, 
    /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill=true,
    /pgf/number format/fixed
}
```

you'll get the desired output:

[image]

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfkeys{
     /pgf/number format/precision=1, 
    /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill=true,
    /pgf/number format/fixed
}
\begin{axis}[
ybar, ymax=4, ymin=0,
%enlargelimits=0.10,
legend style={at={(0.5,-0.20)},
anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
ylabel={Surface Roughness (nm)},
xlabel={Substrate},
symbolic x coords={Glass,Silicon,PEN},
xtick=data,
nodes near coords,
nodes near coords align={vertical},
]
\addplot [fill= white] coordinates {(Glass,2.4) (Silicon,1.1) (PEN,1.8)};
\addplot [fill = black] coordinates  {(Glass,1.1) (Silicon,0.2) (PEN,1.0)};

\legend{Profilometer,AFM}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} 
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks Jake......So nice of you...:) problem solved...:)

Answer (score 6):

A way is to exploit the [`siunitx`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) package similarly to:  [pgfplots: Set exponent of scientific number format for nodes near coords](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96152/pgfplots-set-exponent-of-scientific-number-format-for-nodes-near-coords)

The code:

```
\documentclass[png,tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfkeys{
     /pgf/number format/precision=1, 
    /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill=true
}
\begin{axis}[
ybar, ymax=4, ymin=0,
%enlargelimits=0.10,
legend style={at={(0.5,-0.20)},
anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
ylabel={Surface Roughness (nm)},
xlabel={Substrate},
symbolic x coords={Glass,Silicon,PEN},
xtick=data,
nodes near coords={\pgfmathfloattofixed{\pgfplotspointmeta}% Convert floating point to fixed point
        \num[
            round-mode=places,
            round-precision = 1,
        ]{\pgfmathresult}},
nodes near coords align={vertical},
]
\addplot [fill= white] coordinates {(Glass,2.4) (Silicon,1.1) (PEN,1.8)};
\addplot [fill = black] coordinates  {(Glass,1.1) (Silicon,0.2) (PEN,1.0)};

\legend{Profilometer,AFM}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The result:
[image]

Comment: Thanks Claudio for your kind reply. Problem is solved :)